# Bootstrap 4 carousel not working with AngularJS UI-Bootstrap

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to use angular based carousel in my bootstrap 4 website. When I use bootstrap 3(bootstrap.min.css) its working good. when I try change bootstrap 4 (bootstrap.min.js) its not working. I don't know how to modify the carousel slider for bootstrap 4 angular version. I have tried the below code. Anyone help me to achieve this.

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/testdesigner/aq9Laaew/226984/)

```js
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);

function CarouselDemoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.myInterval = 3000;
  $scope.slides = [{
      image: 'https://eadb.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/placeholder.jpg'
    },

    {
      image: 'https://eadb.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/placeholder.jpg'
    },

    {
      image: 'https://eadb.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/placeholder.jpg'
    },

    {
      image: 'https://eadb.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/placeholder.jpg'
    }
  ];


}
//# sourceURL=pen.js
```

```css
#slides_control>div {
  height: 200px;
}

img {
  margin: auto;
  width: 400px;
}

#slides_control {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 20px;
  margin-left: -200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- ========== Meta Tags ========== -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="Association - Corporate Business Template">
  <title>Template</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!--<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->


</head>

<body>

  <div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="CarouselDemoCtrl" id="slides_control">
      <div>
        <carousel interval="myInterval">
          <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
            <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h4>Slide {{$index+1}}</h4>
            </div>
          </slide>
        </carousel>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- boostrap 4 -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- boostrap 4 -->

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.10.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your example is including jQuery twice - that's going to cause issues if your "real" code is doing the same thing.

Comment: @TiesonT. after removed the jquery also same problem

Comment: The slide class is different in BS4 (`carousel-item`) (see http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/carousel/), so that Angular script is outputting the wrong markup for Bootstrap 4. I assume you'd have to switch to something like https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home

Comment: UI-Bootstrap does not support Bootstrap 4. Instead use [UI Bootstrap 4](https://morgul.github.io/ui-bootstrap4). Bootstrap components written in pure AngularJS by the AngularUI Team. Ported to Bootstrap 4 by [Morgul](https://github.com/Morgul).

Comment: @georgeawg Okay. Noted.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is carousel directive in [ui bootstrap 4](https://morgul.github.io/ui-bootstrap4/#!#carousel)

> ### UI Bootstrap 4
>
> Bootstrap components written in pure AngularJS by the AngularUI Team
>
> Ported to Bootstrap 4 by [Morgul](https://github.com/Morgul)

```
<div uib-carousel active="active" interval="myInterval" no-wrap="noWrapSlides">
  <div uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in slides track by slide.id" index="slide.id">
    <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h4>Slide {{slide.id}}</h4>
      <p>{{slide.text}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

carousel depends on angular-ui-bootstrap which depends on bootstrap3

you are using bootstrap4, therefore angular-ui-bootstrap is outputting wrong html

change:

```
<div uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in slides track by slide.id" index="slide.id">
```

to:

```
<div uib-slide class="carousel-item" ng-repeat="slide in slides track by slide.id" index="slide.id">
```

then remove bootstrap3

Answer (score -1):

As Tieson already mentioned in the comment, this can be mostly because of the multiple jQuery references your code.